# SQL: UIDs is in main table and table that I need to join. But I need to print those ones that are not in the second table

Tags: sql, database, join

I've an excercise to do for university class (SQL). It goes like this: 'Write a query that prints the addresses of library members, who have children born before 1 January 1996. The records that intrest us are ones of the members who don't have any book borrowed currently'.

[Here's the diagram of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHYk6.png)

I need to join a couple tables here. I managed to write the first part and it works:

```
select member.member_no, member.firstname, member.middleinitial, member.lastname, adult.street, adult.city
from member
  join adult on member.member_no = adult.member_no
  join juvenile on juvenile.adult_member_no = member.member_no
where juvenile.birth_date < '1/1/1996'
```

However, I'm struggling with the last part. Obviously, the 'loan' table shows only the books that are borrowed and I need to print UIDs of those library members, who don't hold any book at the moment. How to perform join on something that doesn't exsist in the table? I think the columns 'isbn', 'copy', 'title', 'out date' and 'due date' are irrelevant for this query, therefore I must work with 'member no'. But how?

I thought about something like: 'join loan on member.member_no = loan.member_no where member.member_no not like loan.member_no', but it didn't work. Please help.

I'd be also very grateful if someone could describe how the solution proposed works. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you store people in different tables depending on their age?

Comment: @jarlh I don’t understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you have one table for adults and another one for juveniles? (Instead of storing them in the same table.)

Comment: @jarlh that’s a database provided by the University. I know it makes no sensie, but we must work on it.